# C# - Flatten Nested Json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net, flatten

I have multiple JSONs with different layouts and i'm trying to create some code to flatten these and then turn it into a Datatable.

Example JSON 1

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "uri": "myuri.com",
          "type": "String"
        },
        "jobNumber": "123456789",
        "numberVacancy": "1",
        "some_obj": {
          "__metadata": {
            "uri": "myuri.com",
            "type": "String"
          },
          "code": "000012356"
        },
        "anothernested": {
          "results": [
            {
              "__metadata": {
                "uri": "myuri.com",
                "type": "String"
              },
              "picklistLabels": {
                "results": [
                  {
                    "__metadata": {
                      "uri": "myuri.com",
                      "type": "String"
                    },
                    "label": "Casual"
                  },
                  {
                    "__metadata": {
                      "uri": "myuri.com",
                      "type": "String"
                    },
                    "label": "Casual"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "uri": "myuri.com",
          "type": "String"
        },
        "jobNumber": "987654321",
        "numberVacancy": "1",
        "some_obj": {
          "__metadata": {
            "uri": "myuri.com",
            "type": "String"
          },
          "code": "000012356"
        },
        "anothernested": {
          "results": [
            {
              "__metadata": {
                "uri": "myuri.com",
                "type": "String"
              },
              "picklistLabels": {
                "results": [
                  {
                    "__metadata": {
                      "uri": "myuri.com",
                      "type": "String"
                    },
                    "label": "Casual"
                  },
                  {
                    "__metadata": {
                      "uri": "myuri.com",
                      "type": "String"
                    },
                    "label": "Casual"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Example of how I would like the JSON to be flattened into a Datatable.

| __metadata/uri | __metadata/type | jobNumber | numberVacancy | some_obj/__metadata/uri | some_obj/__metadata/type | some_obj/code | anothernested/results/0/__metadata/uri | anothernested/results/0/__metadata/type | anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/0/__metadata/uri | anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/0/__metadata/type | anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/0/label | anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/1/__metadata/uri | anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/1/__metadata/type | anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/1/label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| myuri.com | String | 123456789 | 1 | myuri.com | String | 12356 | myuri.com | String | myuri.com | String | Casual | myuri.com | String | Casual |
| myuri.com | String | 987654321 | 1 | myuri.com | String | 12356 | myuri.com | String | myuri.com | String | Casual | myuri.com | String | Casual |

I will be flattening the JSON from the d.results index.

So far, I have this which will flatten each separate Json inside the results array into a dictionary of string. However, I am unsure about how to convert this into a datatable, keeping into mind that sometimes the elements in the dictionary may not be in the same order or there may be more or less elements in each of the JSON arrays.

```
IEnumerable<JToken> jTokens = jsonObject.Descendants().Where(p => p.Count() == 0);
results1 = jTokens.Aggregate(new Dictionary<string, string>(), (properties, jToken) =>
                    {
                        properties.Add(jToken.Path, jToken.ToString());
                        return properties;
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a datatable from your source json you will need this code:

```
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
List<string> jpaths = jsonObject.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().Where(jp => jp.Value is JArray).Select(jp => jp.Path).ToList();
List<JToken> rowtokens = jsonObject.SelectTokens("$.d.results.[*]").ToList();

DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();
resultTable.Columns.AddRange(((JObject)rowtokens[0]).Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().Where(jp => jp.Value is JValue).Select(jp => new DataColumn(jp.Path)).ToArray());
foreach (JToken rowtoken in rowtokens)
{
    resultTable.Rows.Add(((JObject)rowtoken).Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().Where(jp => jp.Value is JValue).Select(jp => jp.Value.ToString()).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly first go. Flattened the whole JSON and kept each object separate.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source lib for your needs.

```
using (var r = new ChoJSONReader("*** YOUR JSON FILE PATH ***")
    .WithJSONPath("$..d.results")
    .Configure(c => c.NestedColumnSeparator = '/')
    )
{
    var dt = r.AsDataTable();
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Dump());
}
```

**Output:**

```
__metadata/uri,__metadata/type,jobNumber,numberVacancy,some_obj/__metadata/uri,some_obj/__metadata/type,some_obj/code,anothernested/results/0/__metadata/uri,anothernested/results/0/__metadata/type,anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/0/__metadata/uri,anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/0/__metadata/type,anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/0/label,anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/1/__metadata/uri,anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/1/__metadata/type,anothernested/results/0/picklistLabels/results/1/label
myuri.com,String,123456789,1,myuri.com,String,000012356,myuri.com,String,myuri.com,String,Casual,myuri.com,String,Casual
myuri.com,String,987654321,1,myuri.com,String,000012356,myuri.com,String,myuri.com,String,Casual,myuri.com,String,Casual
```

Sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DXBOYC

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.